# How to handle spring boot logout redirect in nginx?

Tags: nginx, spring-boot, reverse-proxy

We have a spring boot web application application which redirects logout to index page with 301 redirect.
The following snipper we used in nginx to handle the redirect. But it is not getting redirected. 502 Bad gateway error is displayed.

```
location /UI/
{
proxy_pass http://localhost:6080/UI/;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect / /;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
}
location @handle_redirects 
{
set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
}
```

Where UI is the name of the web application WAR running in tomcat.

In spring boot security.xml the following line is there.

Any advice?

Comment: Try using `proxy_redirect http://localhost:6080/ /`; and remove `error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;`. See if that does the job

Comment: Thanks i will try this